# Sitecore MVC, Controller accessing item fields without creating a model

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

Is there a way to access a sitecore item field without creating a model? So that I can build a more dynamic template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have in your view:

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@model RenderingModel
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Title")<br />
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Image")<br />
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Text")<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Model Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel  contains Item and PageItem fields. You can use these properties to access Item fields without adding them to model.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore has an extension on the HtmlHelper, you can use that for rendering fields (a.o.). The razor syntax would look like:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("FieldNameOrID")
```

Take a look at this post for some more background info: http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2012/06/about-mvc-helpers-with-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx